# Multiple regression equation

Tags: statistics, reference-request

Can someone please recommend me a good book to understand multiple regression? I need to know how to calculate the equation of multiple regression with two independent variables The one I have does not contain this topic. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Applied Linear Regression Model, by Kutner, Nachtshein, Neter. fourth edition.